# Spacy NER custom patterns ValueError: Can't read file error .json?

Tags: python, ubuntu, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am using Spacy to get NER tags and have created custom patterns that I want to add to my NER ruler. It works when running this on my local machine. However, I am now trying to run the code in an ubuntu server and I keep running into the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nlp/model.py", line 57, in <module>
    data = get_ner_tags(data)
  File "/home/ubuntu/scripts/dir1/nlp/py_scripts/features.py", line 61, in get_ner_tags
    .from_disk("scripts/dir1/nlp/py_scripts/patterns.jsonl")
  File "/home/ubuntu/scripts/dir1/venv-dir1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/pipeline/entityruler.py", line 477, in from_disk
    self.add_patterns(patterns)
  File "/home/ubuntu/scripts/dir1/venv-dir1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/pipeline/entityruler.py", line 307, in add_patterns
    for entry in patterns:
  File "/home/ubuntu/scripts/dir1/venv-dir1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/srsly/_json_api.py", line 109, in read_jsonl
    file_path = force_path(path)
  File "/home/ubuntu/scripts/dir1/venv-dir1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/srsly/util.py", line 24, in force_path
    raise ValueError(f"Can't read file: {location}")
ValueError: Can't read file: scripts/dir1/nlp/py_scripts/patterns.jsonl
```

This is the code I use:

```
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()

#adding custom ruler with patterns
ruler = nlp.add_pipe('entity_ruler', before ='ner')\
        .from_disk("scripts/dir1/nlp/py_scripts/patterns.jsonl")
data['spacy_ner_label'] = data['clean_words'].apply(lambda x: [y.label_ for y in list(nlp(x).ents)])
```

It works when running on my local machine, and if I create new directories and run the scripts in there. But, I can't get it to work using it in the ubuntu box.

Comment: I don't think so, but are you sure this file has the permissions needed when using ubuntu box? Just make sure of this by running `ls -l [filename]`.

Comment: @mjoy Do you have any updates on this? Did you find any workaround?